# In S01E08, how did Jessica do it in 'What Would Jessica Do?'

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, jessica-jones

In S01E08 of Jessica Jones, how was Jessica able to knock out the 2 servants. Even she & Kilgrave had consumed the food. But both were fine until Jessica shoots Kilgrave with Sufentanil shot.

Comment: why is this in spoiler markup?  this doesn't spoil any major plot items

Comment: While watching, I was like, OK, maybe the story is taking a turn in an unexpected direction & then BAM! *This is what Jessica Would Do*. I would be mighty pissed with the spoiler. So

Comment: @DForck42 how does "two main characters are drugged until one of them save each other" not count as a spoiler?

Comment: @cde Over here we don't mind spoiler in question body, just avoid them in question title. And dizzle's point is not wrong either, this spoiler doesn't give much information of any plot either.

Comment: @AnkitSharma why did you remove the spoiler? Now it appears clearly below the question title on the main page. Than what use is avoiding it in the title. Please revert your edit

Comment: @KharoBangdo First, it doesn't spoil much useful stuff, not even understandable enough till you know that episode. Second on Movies and TV we avoid spoiler markup to make question more readable because we don't appreciate empty boxes till its of some use. On the side note if someone read a question which explicitly mentioned episode no in title must be aware of spoilyness to go further. You can take help of meta to understand all spoiler specific rules, there are many question already present on the topic.

Comment: Related meta post http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/82/1190

Comment: @AnkitSharma my only issue is that now the spoiler appears below the question title on the main page. So, if somebody hasn't seen the episode yet & browses this site questions, he will be exposed to the spoiler even though he didn't click on the specific question marked S01E08. Its unmissable. Anyway, U are the mod. Dont want to use this as discussion as I know this is not a place for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There wasn't any thing in her or his food.

She just drugged the two servants so they won't hurt themselves (because Kilgrave compelled them to kill themselves if Jessica tried any thing) , and once the two servants passed out, she drugged Kilgrave with a sufentanil shot

Edit: About how she drugged the servants, The show didn't address this in a clear manner, but it's obvious from the scene that she put something in their food (She brought the food and put on the plates while she was alone, and Kilgrave asked her to eat from his plate to assure him) The trick is that she drugged the two servants not Kilgrave

Comment: But how did she drug the servants? Be more specific

Comment: @KharoBangdo The show didn't address this point in a clear manner, but it's obvious from the scene that she put something in their food (She brought the food and put on the plates while she was alone, and Kilgrave ask her to eat from his plate to assure him) The trick is that she drugged the servants not him